# AppWidget only updates once

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a problem with an appwidget. It doesn't have a configuration activity. When I set `android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"` ( know this shouldn't be done but it's just for testing) in the emulator the `onUpdate(...)` function is called every 10 seconds. But when i install my app on my real phone (motorola milestone) `onUpdate(...)` is only called when I add the widget to the home screen. And never again.
Any ideas why this happens on the real device but not in the emulator?

Comment: Motorola Milestone features Android v2.0, v2.0.1, v2.1, maybe you have to wait more time for the widget update =).

Comment: Is this means when your set 10000, It also update once? Or will update per 30 mi

Comment: it will be called every 30 minutes. see my comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Sdk are u using?

#### since Android sdk 1.6 the widget update minimum period is 30 minutes.

Comment: that could be it. the emulator runs 1.5, my milestone runs 2.1. I'll try and set it to 30 minutes.
Is this minimum period documented somewhere?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis
aha there it is... "Note: Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more than once every 30 minutes." i tested it in an 2.2 emulator and onUpdate(...) doesn't get called every 10 seconds, too.